# Best possible ways to disable index before insert operation and enable back Index after insert

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sql-server-2014, columnstore

I'm planning to create a Non-clustered columnstore index on SQL Server 2014.

But non clustered column store index is read-only and cannot perform DML operations, we need to disable before insert and enable back after insert.

What are the best possible ways to perform this task?

Comment: my bad Typo error. Yes read-only

Answer (score 16):

Simply disable the index and perform a rebuild. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn589806(v=sql.120).aspx

```
ALTER INDEX mycolumnstoreindex ON mytable DISABLE;  
-- update mytable --  
ALTER INDEX mycolumnstoreindex on mytable REBUILD
```